# How do I configure multiple keyboard layouts in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

There is `Settings > Keyboard > Layout` and there is something called `iBus` and `input methods`.

I were using `Keyboard > Layout` GUI to configure my layouts in **13.10** and it worked fine. But after update to **14.04** something called `iBus` appeared and now my shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is not working. Looks like something is intercepting this hotkey. If I set hotkey to something else in `Keyboard > Layout` it's working: I can change my layout, but if I set it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> it's not working at all.

What are those different methods of keyboard input configuration? What method is preferred? How do I enable only one preferred method and disable another one in order to prevent conflicts?

There is `iBus` icon on the panel. When I click on it, a drop-down menu appears with two input methods. But when I select one of them, nothing happens. The input language is still the same.

Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what all the technical details behind all of this, but here's the method you can use to configure multiple keyboard layouts in latest Xubuntu 14.04.

1. Open `Settings Manager`
2. Launch `Input Method`
3. Hit `OK` and/or `Yes`
4. Select `None` from the list of input methods and click `OK` probably several times
5. Open `Keyboard Input Methods`
6. In the `Keyboard Shortcuts` section remove all the keys associated with `Next input method` command
7. Open `Keyboard`, select `Layout` tab and configure your layouts and shortcuts

### In case there is no "Keyboard Input Methods"

1. Open `All Settings`
2. Choose `Input Method`
3. Hit `OK` and/or `Yes` if you asked (probably several times)
4. Chose `REMOVE`
5. Hit `OK` and/or `Yes` until window is closed
6. Open `Keyboard`, select `Layout` tab and configure your layouts and shortcuts

It should work fine now.

Comment: Keep an eye on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322 too...

Answer (score 1):

I had problems using my ASUS EeePC 1015PX with Xubuntu 14.04 defaulting to the European keyboard layout, so every time I logged in I had to change it in Terminal.

But now, until the bug is fixed, you can create a start-up script in Xubuntu so it configures to whatever you want on log in (and considering my laptop suffers from the black screen after sleep bug, I am shutting down and logging in a lot these days!)

Menu >> Settings Manager >> System >> Session and Startup >> tab Application Autostart

Click +Add button, then fill in the three boxes as follows:

Name: USKeyboard (or call it whatever you want)

Description: Change keyboard layout to US on login.

Command: setxkbmap -layout us

Click OK

Reboot and test your keyboard (for me, that means making sure SHIFT-2 gives @ and not " and vice versa, as well as some other character changes such as |).

You will have to google the abbreviation for other regions' keyboard layouts but the principle should be the same. Once you find out the abbreviations, you can change the layout in Terminal using the setxkbmap -layout command, appended with the region's code, whenever you want, but with each reboot it will default back to whatever you chose in your startup script.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! I'm not sure it directly answers my question, but I believe others will benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

IBus is the modern Unix/Linux keyboard input method. Funnily, I experienced a problem because of the exact opposite of your situation: IBus wasn't turned on by default in a fresh Xubuntu installation. IBus inputs AND switching methods can be configured in the IBus config Window which can be found in "Settings" -> "Keyboard Input Methods" (with an "i" icon).