# How to set French AZERTY keyboard layout in Xubuntu?

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout

I need to test something on French AZERTY keyboard layout but I can't find it in `xfce4-keyboard-settings` app, is it possible to set it? Is it name like something else?

Comment: It should be named French, just select the desired variant. http://askubuntu.com/questions/450625/how-do-i-configure-multiple-keyboard-layouts-in-xubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout named *French (Azerty)* was added in 16.10. One way to get it, if you are on 14.04 or 16.04, is to install the `xkb-data` package from this PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~gunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/togo-kblayout

OTOH I think that the basic *French* layout actually is AZERTY as well.

Answer (score 0):

If only for testing it should be enough to use `setxkbmap` with the parameter `fr` for French,

```
$ setxkbmap fr
$ echo azerty
azerty
$ setxkbmap se
$ echo qwerty
qwerty
```